# Kotlin best practice: val of object fields

Tags: variables, kotlin

While converting my project from Java to Kotlin, I saw that Android Studio created another type of declaration than I'm used to. I want to know if this declaration is better practice than the normal object declaration.

My normal declaration: `val level : Level = ship.levels.first`

But by converting my project, this was put in another way: `val (_, buildTime, _, _, components) = ship.levels.first`

I guess the converter does this because I only need those 2 fields but I wonder if there are other advantages of using this instead of the casual object declaration.

Thanks in advance for helping me understand this better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a [deconstructing declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html).

It's available for any type that supports the `component1()` etc. convention, which includes lists, maps, and data classes.

Some of the benefits of using deconstructuring declarations are:

- No need to write `it` (or the bound variable name) every time you want to access a property.
- Only use the properties you care about, meaning you can't perform operations on the destructured object in error.

But it's really a style choice and you have to decide which is best, or which you prefer, on a case-by-case basis.